# Get path for the file being run and not the dir of where the call is from

Tags: python

Say I have the following `/home/my_user/files/path.py` which contains `print(os.getcwd())` and I from `/home/` run

`python3 ./my_user/files/path.py`

I get the output `/home/`. Is there a way to print the folder of which the file being run is e.g `/home/my_user/files` independantly of where the file is run from?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the absolute path of the directory of the executed python file

```py
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the directory of the Python file, not the working directory:

```
import os.path

print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file's realpath, not the current directory

```py
import os

os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```